# Metamodel - Sql Server 2008 identification for LOB data

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, apache-metamodel

We are trying to extract data from different databases into some flat file format,  using a `Apache MetaModel`.  With `ORACLE`, for a `LOB` column (either `CLOB` or `BLOB`)  we  get `isLarge()=true`.  But for the same column with `SQL Server 2008 R2` we are getting `false` for it. In `SQL Server 2008 R2` our `LOB` column is `varChar(Max)` for CLOB  and `varbinary(Max)` for BLOB.

Is there any way to handle both databases with one solution?

Answer (score 0):

Apache MetaModel has a system property that you can set which will make it automatically convert all CLOBs to Strings and all BLOBs to byte-arrays.

You can set this property either via it's string value on the command line or such:

```
-Dmetamodel.jdbc.convert.lobs=true
```

Or you can do it from code, in which case there's a convenient constant available for you:

```
System.setProperty(JdbcDataContext.SYSTEM_PROPERTY_CONVERT_LOBS, true);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

One possible approach is to use [java.sql.Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.BLOB). Any database system supporting JDBC should reliable map to this types.

JDBC defines [getMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29) method, which return information about all columns of a ResultSet. The key method is the [getColumnType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType%28int%29) that return the above sql type, (e.g. 2004 fro BLOB).

Here a small example using Groovy instead of Java to check column of the table **my_tab**

```
def stmt = con.createStatement() 

def rs = stmt.executeQuery('select * from my_tab')

def rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
def colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount()

println "getColumnCount ${colCount}"

colCount.times {i ->
  println "---------------------------------"
  println "columnName ${rsmd.getColumnName(i+1)}"
  println "columnTypeName ${rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i+1)}" 
  println "columnType ${rsmd.getColumnType(i+1)}"   
}
```

results in

```
getColumnCount 3
---------------------------------
columnName C1
columnTypeName BLOB
columnType 2004

---------------------------------
columnName C2
columnTypeName CLOB
columnType 2005

---------------------------------
columnName C3
columnTypeName DATE
columnType 93
```

I have no much experience beyond Oracle with the getMetaData method, but in my opinion this is the easiest approach to attack this problem.

Comment: it would be valuable for my and possible others to know if the down-vote is based on some problem with proposed approach or it is only a subjective matter.